# Laravel 5 Excel installation failure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel

I am having a rough time trying to install the Laravel Excel (http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs) package to my Laravel 5. Here's what I've done so far:

- Added `"maatwebsite/excel": "2.*"` to my require, `composer update`
  finishes just fine and I have all the package files
- Added `'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider',` to providers array
- Added `'Excel' => 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel',` to aliases array

Here's the problem - when I try running `php artisan vendor:publish`, it tells me `Nothing to publish for tag [].`

When I use `php artisan tinker` and run `$excel = App::make('excel')`, it tells me `ReflectionException with message 'Class excel does not exist'`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to run `composer dumpautoload` and then publish again?

Comment: @lesssugar yes, I tried that.

Comment: I've just tried installing the package both on Laravel 5.0.* and Laravel 5.1.* and it worked just fine for both, so perhaps the problem is specific to your environment.

Comment: try `artisan vendor:publish --tag=config`

Comment: @NaN `Nothing to publish for tag [config].`

Comment: hmm  can you confirm you have the file` /vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/config/excel.php`? If you do, just copy that file into your config directory as that is all the publish command does anyway

Comment: Copied, but that doesn't fix my error related to Laravel not finding the class. :(

Comment: @NAN Publishing the configuration file is not a requirement for the package to work, it's only there so you can adjust a the configuration if needed, without actually editing the vendor specific copy of the config file. Salkz please try setting up a fresh installation of Laravel and installing the package there. This should at least determine if the problem is specific to the app you're currently working with or if it is a general enviroment issue.

Comment: @Bogdan Thanks, I will try and post an update later.

Comment: I've had both errors in the past with a package and they had to do with me forgetting to add the lines to the `providers` array and the `aliases` array. Probably a stupid question, but are you sure you put them in the right spot? What file did you put them in?

Comment: Also can you check if `Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider` and `Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel` classes are in `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`?

Comment: @Björn I put them into `config/app.php` and yes - the classes are in `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`.

Comment: @Bogdan I set up a new VM, did everything as before and it works. My guess is that I originally configured something while being root and the permissions are wrong somewhere...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was facing the same problem and came to this question but there wasn't any clear solution. So I keep searching and found a simple solution.

The problem is related with the cached config file. So for Laravel 5.1, just clear the cache

```
php artisan config:cache
```

and it worked perfectly in my case. [Source](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/510#issuecomment-128701910)

Comment: thank you very much, it worked! been stuck here for like 5 hours just because of this

Comment: Thanks! I had cached the config and forgot all about it.